# Store references to Dask Futures in a Flask/FastAPI Application

Tags: python, dask, endpoint, concurrent.futures, fastapi

I'm building a FastAPI application that has an endpoint to trigger a Dask computation. The API endpoint sends this call to the Dask scheduler and just returns the key of the `Future`.

**`trigger`**

```
x = client.submit
    (
        function_name,
        arg1,
        arg2
    )
return x.key
```

I have two other endpoints to retrieve the status and result of the task, which take the `key` as input.

**`status`**

```
status = Future(key=key, client=client).status
return status
```

**`result`**

```
result = Future(key=key, client=client).result()
return result
```

Of course, this way, I lose the reference to the future after `trigger` returns, in which case Dask doesn't compute this anymore. So even if the key is given to the client, we get the status as `pending` forever.

What I'm doing now is storing references to the Future object as a python dictionary in the application, which works. But ideally, I would like my API application to be stateless. What would be store these Futures outside this application? Are there good caching libraries in Python that can store Python objects (with references)?

Answer (score -1):

Try using Flask + Celery to handle the background Dask computation. Below are few links for reference:

1. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/celery/
2. https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask
3. https://medium.com/@frassetto.stefano/flask-celery-howto-d106958a15fe